# Is it possible to show an invoke Button without using a CardAction inside of a ThumbnailCard or HeroCard?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I would like to present the user with invoke buttons below some HTML formatted text.  I have currently set the Text of the Activity to my HTML fragment and attached a ThumbnailCard with only my CardAction(s) to the Activity.  This sort of works, but renders as multiple replys from the bot which disconnects the content of the post and the buttons (which represent actions in response to the post).  Another option may be a different card implementation focused on Text/HTML presentation and formatting rather than thumbnail/hero style presentation?

For context, this particular use-case is a chatops bot sending a notification to a public channel (or private conversation) about a job failure or system error and the button(s) represent actions one could take in response (Ignore Failure, Reset Job, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use a card?

You can always do a herocard with just Text content and buttons.  No need for Title, Subtitle, or Images...  And the Text content can support HTML.